# Oracle sql to solve the sql query with select statement in the column list that fetches multiple value

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select * 
from  (
  select table_name 
  from user_tab_cols 
  where column_name='CONTRACT_NUMBER'
)  
where contarct_number ='U5490231'
```

in this select statement, I  am  trying to get the list of tables  from user_tab_cols
and then do a

```
select * 
from table_name 
where column_name='U5490231'.
```

trying to find a select statement on this basis but getting error

Comment: Please post error you get

Comment: You'd need dynamic SQL to do that, but... why do you need this at all? Sounds like there is a major design problem somewhere.

Comment: You have a typo in your code **contarct**_number

Answer (score 0):

```
Oracle Query:
 v_table NVARCHAR(MAX)
 v_whereCol NVARCHAR(MAX)
 v_WhereParam NVARCHAR(MAX)

v_WhereParam := 'CONTRACT_NUMBER'
v_whereCol := 'U5490231'

SELECT  E.table_name INTO v_table
FROM    user_tab_cols AS E
WHERE   E.column_name = v_WhereParam
 v_query NVARCHAR(MAX)
v_query := 'Select * from ' || v_table || ' Where contarct_number =''' || v_whereCol || ''''
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_query
```

Comment: Please check this one.

Comment: sorry  about delayed response .but this code doesn't work .  I tried   reworking on it   also .